Encode an array of items conforming to an Encodable protocol
I was surprised recently to find that this:
protocol A: Encodable {}

class B: A {
    var x = 3
}

class C: A {
    var y = 4
}

let items: [A] = [B()]
let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(items)

Fails in Swift with:

Type 'any A' cannot conform to 'Encodable'

while this works:
let items: [B] = [B()]
let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(items)

Apparently the issue is that protocols do not conform to themselves. A workaround is provided in this answer.
I understand the reasoning and the workaround in the answers, but it is still quite inconvenient. Both of those answers are from ~2017; is there a cleaner way to solve this in swift 5?

Let's just say you would be able to make this work but how are you going to decode it then? You will have an array of json values that could be anything so how could you possibly write decoding code for that?

it's a good point, and I guess the swifty way doesn't do this. In my usecase, the conforming classes identify themselves with a type attribute. This is intermediate debug output, it's not a model that's serialized and deserialized into the same model, so it's not really a problem

That said, just because something is Encodable doesn't mean it has to be Decodable, or vice versa. I've written quite a few systems that are unidirectional in this way, in both directions. There's nothing wrong with being able to encode [any Encodable]. We just currently can't. It's still on the notional roadmap (i.e. it's not promised, but it is desired) to make this possible. That said, it is unlikely that it would ever be possible to decode [any Decodable]. There's no general solution to that.

Sample workaround :)
struct AnyEncodable: Encodable {
    
    let item: any Encodable
    
    func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(self.item)
    }
}

let items: [A] = [B()]
let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(items.map { AnyEncodable(item: $0) })


Short and sweet - thank you!

It's not correct to call item.encode(to: encoder), because you'll break encoding strategies; instead, you should fetch a singleValueEncodingContainer() and encode the value into that. See https://forums.swift.org/t/encodable-incorrect-json-string-with-url-and-decimal-existentials/68713/2 and the linked threads for more information

@ItaiFerber you are right. I have corrected my answer according to your suggestion. Thank you for your vigilance

The update looks great! Upvoted :)

encode(_:) is a generic method which takes a concrete static type conforming to Encodable. The generic design of the method is the reason why you cannot use the protocol itself. The compiler needs to know the structure of the static type to be able to synthesize the protocol method encode(_:).

Encode an array of items conforming to an Encodable protocol

is fine, but you are trying to

Encode an array of items being the Encodable protocol

which is impossible. This is valid since 2017 till today.

Thanks for taking the time to answer and for pointing out the subtle language differences - I like the emphasis on being the encoding protocol vs conforming to it.
I must admit thoug I am most interested in workarounds.. so the workaround outlined in the other ticket is still the best we can do?
